# Pushing index.html file to GitHub using git

Tags: git, github

When I push my index.html file to GitHub using git do the additional folders I created for that particular project get pushed too, folders like images and pages or do I have to manually push them, even though on git it said they've been committed it doesn't show on my GitHub all I see is the `README.md` and `index.html` files and none other

I thought when I pushed the `index.html` file to GitHub it'll all get pushed.
But when I tried opening the code using GitHub the pages linked to it couldn't be found on the server

Comment: You don't push files with git, you push commits. Whatever is committed, gets pushed. If you don't see committed files on the web interface of GitHub, maybe you're looking at the wrong branch?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities: either the directories are empty, or they are non-empty.

- **Are the directories empty?**  If so, then the answer is:

  git is only concerned with files; if a certain file is in a directory, it will automatically create the directory. If a directory is empty, it never gets committed. If a directory becomes empty, then it automatically disappears from the repository.

  When people need a specific directory to exist in the repository, they sometimes place a dummy file in it, just in order to coerce git to keep that directory in existence.
- **Are the directories non-empty?** If so, then the answer is:

  You only committed "index.html", so you should not expect anything but "index.html" to be committed.

Comment: Third possibility: OP is pushing to a branch like "topic" but it is looking at "main".

Comment: @VLAZ true, but you have to set the cap somewhere on how far you will go with assumptions about what the OP might be doing wrong. I mean, maybe he is looking at the wrong computer. Maybe he is looking at the right computer but the wrong monitor. Maybe he is speaking some language which is very much like English but in fact not at all English, and in that language, his question as stated means something entirely different. You never know.

Comment: (That last bit about language was Douglas-Adams-y; I am very proud of it.)

Comment: I thought it's a reasonable assumption to make, since GitHub by default shows you the main branch, and you have to manually navigate to another. And since OP seems inexperienced, *not* navigating to another branch in the GitHub UI seems quite plausible. Since also, in my experience, it's a common problem for a lot of people. Myself included - I've mistakenly looked at the wrong branch in the Azure DevOps UI when I meant to look at another. DevOps, similar to GitHub, shows you the main branch by default.